# Android eclipse yo xcode?

Tags: android, xcode, eclipse, export

Is there any way to export an android application project I have already working on eclipse to xcode for being used in ios? I Heard Google developed a Java por that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There's no magical conversion tool. Both the platforms and languages involved are significantly different.